# Responsive horizontal website with fullscreen width per section

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscrollpane

I'm building a site using [this tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/02/responsive-horizontal-layout/).

I'm trying to modify it so that each section extends to fill the browser window to the right instead of showing the other chapters. I tried just increasing the width of each section to 100% but it breaks the sliding/scrolling functionality.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Just setting the width to 100% for the sections. My other idea I'm working on now is setting the width of each section dynamically using JQuery to the width of the browser. But trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have borders or paddings on current block try use {box-sizing:border-box;}

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that it has anything to do with the padding or borders. I think the width is a problem when working with the javascript the controls the scrolling function.

Comment: So I got it working kinda but can't get the sections to resize with the correct with when I stretch the browser. I'm using this code with a resize function:
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    // set width of areas
    
    $(".hs-content").css("width", windowWidth);
    $(".hs-content-wrapper").css("width", fullWidth);

Comment: Valid responsive markup do not need a script. Can you show link to your code?